# Can I log into Passport.js by sending post requests from a python application?

Tags: javascript, python, express, passport.js

I made a REST api with Node/express and I added a login feature using Passport.js, I want to be able to login to this from a CLI im making with python.

Im able to send a post request to my login url from my python app and get authorized by passport and send the info i want back to the python program, but once the python program has ended the express app doesn't cache me as logged in and in order to get back any info from the express app i have to send a Post request to the login url every time. The reason I thought this would work is because I can send Post requests from the REST-client extension and the app functions how I want. I have express-session etc set up, like i said it functions how I want with REST-client.

Comment: First, when you say `REST` it is stateless. You should use `token-based` authentication instead of `session-based`. After the successful login, Store the `Access Token` securely and each time when your re-start python application, Fetch the existing token to continue, If it is expired only you will need to re-login.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If my understanding of stateful and stateless is correct its stateless. What im doing after logging in is making additional api calls when needed to get info from a database and thats really it, the rest of the logic will be handled on the python side.  I just want to be able to do that without sending login credentials everytime.  But ill check out token-based authentication as opposed to session-based!